# Designating Maximum record in table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Could anyone help me to achieve this using SQL. I am a very basic user in SQL and tried doing it with GROUP BY in combination with HAVING Clause but it was filtering the records which i dot want to.

All I a want to acieve here is the Relative month column. Wherever there is maximum MonthNUmber the correpsponding column should be designated as "Current Month"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tim Biegeleisen has the right idea, although I think using the windowing variant of `max` would be **much** more elegant (and should, in theory, also be faster, although you should always benchmark all the options instead of just accepting such claims).

```
SELECT ID, 
       EmpName, 
       MonthNumber,
       CASE MonthNumber WHEN MAX(MonthNumber) OVER () THEN 'Current' END
from   mytable;
```

Comment: ...and I agree with your answer +1

Answer (score 3):

You could use a subquery to do this:

```
SELECT ID,
       EmpName,
       MonthNumber,
       CASE WHEN MonthNumber = (SELECT MAX(MonthNumber) FROM yourTable)
            THEN 'Current' ELSE NULL END AS RelativeMonth
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand may be [MAX](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp) will serve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT RelativeMonth FROM table WHERE MonthNumber = (SELECT Max(MonthNumber) FROM table)`